# How can RDF be defined using RDFS and OWL?

Tags: uri, rdf, semantic-web, owl, rdfs

I just browsed this [uri](/questions/tagged/uri) http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns and found this prefix declarations:

```
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> .
```

if this [uri](/questions/tagged/uri) supposed to define [rdf](/questions/tagged/rdf)? How can we use [rdfs](/questions/tagged/rdfs) and [owl](/questions/tagged/owl) in this document if we all know that [rdf](/questions/tagged/rdf) is the basis of those languages?

Comment: I don’t understand the last question. Do you really ask *how* this can be done (if yes, your code snippet is an example of it, isn’t it?), or do you mean to imply that it doesn’t make any sense (to "define" RDF in a document that makes use of RDF)?

Comment: I believe the question is how can RDF be defined using RDFS and OWL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that in this example RDFS and OWL are purely namespaces - there is no hierarchy of classes or properties, nor any class restrictions or other RDFS or OWL constructs.

The basic definitions are not included in actual RDFS or OWL ontologies - this is not a default top level ontology (for example, the label for `rdf:type` cannot be found searching in an RDFS ontology, unless it contains explicitly these triples.

You could consider this example a metaontology - looks more like a convenient format to hold a few basic information, which could be embedded in the specs instead.